# how can I sort three (more) arrays according to one (strings and numbers)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want sort the first array and have the second array and the third follow the same sort as the first. And if i choose to sort the second one the other two will follow again. As you can see below i need it to work for strings and numbers. Any advice for a good algorithm would be appreciated. Preferably using The push() method.

```
    let array_one  = ["bravo_one", "charlie_two", "alpha_three", "echo_four", "delta_five"]
    let array_two = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    let array_three = ["golf_one", "zulu_two", "tango_three", "november_four", "kilo_five"]


    // Some Logic expected here
    let new_one = array_one.sort(function(a, b){
        return (a.localeCompare(b));
    })

    let new_two = []
    let new_three = []

    // Exprected Output
    console.log(new_one); // ["alpha_three", "bravo_one", "charlie_two", "delta_five", "echo_four"]
    console.log(new_two); // [3, 1, 2, 5, 4]
    console.log(new_three); // ["tango_three", "golf_one", "zulu_two",  "kilo_five", "november_four"]

    // Some Logic expected here
    let new_one = []

    let new_two = array_two.sort(function(a, b){
        return b.length - a.length;
    })

    let new_three = []

    // Exprected Output
    console.log(new_one); // ["bravo_one", "charlie_two", "alpha_three", "echo_four", "delta_five"]
    console.log(new_two); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    console.log(new_three); // ["golf_one", "zulu_two", "tango_three", "november_four", "kilo_five"]


    // Some Logic expected here
    let new_one = []

    let new_two = []

    let new_three = array_three.sort(function(a, b){
        return (a.localeCompare(b));
    })

    // Exprected Output
    console.log(new_one); // ["bravo_one", "delta_five", "echo_four", "tango_three", "charlie_two"]
    console.log(new_two); // [1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
    console.log(new_three); // ["golf_one", "kilo_five", "november_four", "tango_three", "zulu_two"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_one`, `array_two` and `array_three` look like they should be an object. Especially if `array_one[0]`, `array_two[0]` and `array_three[0]` contain related data.

Either change the way you get that data in the first place, or:

```
var bigarray = array_one.map(function(_,i) {
  return {
    name: array_one[i],
    number: array_two[i],
    extra: array_three[i]
  }
);
```

Now you can sort:

```
bigarray.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});
```

And iterate as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have your data structure set up differently. To facilitate implementation.
New structure to make work easier

```js
var items = [
    {name: 'bravo_two', age: 2, last_name: 'zulu_two'},
    {name: 'alpha_one', age: 1, last_name: 'tango_one'},
    {name: 'charlie_three', age: 3, last_name: 'golf_three'},
    {name: 'echo_five', age: 5, last_name: 'kilo_five'},
    {name: 'delta_four', age: 4, last_name: 'november_four'}
];
function comp(a, b){
    return a.name > b.name ? 1: -1
}
items.sort(comp);
// OR
// items.sort((a, b) => { return a.name > b.name ? 1: -1 });
for(i=0; i<items.length; i++ ){
    console.log(items[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

If you can not change the data structure. The following is an implementation.

```js
var new_one = ["bravo_two", "alpha_one", "charlie_three", "echo_five", "delta_four"];
var new_two = [2, 1, 3, 5, 4];
var new_three = ["zulu_two",  "tango_one", "golf_three", "kilo_five", "november_four"];
var i;

var items = [];
for(i=0;i<new_one.length;i++){
    items.push(
        { name: new_one[i], age: new_two[i], last_name: new_three[i] }
    );
}
// OR
// var items = new_one.map((_,i)=>{ return { name: new_one[i], age: new_two[i], extra: new_three[i] } });

function comp(a, b){
    return a.name > b.name ? 1: -1
}
items.sort(comp);
// OR
// items.sort((a, b) => { return a.name > b.name ? 1: -1 });

for(i=0; i<items.length; i++ ){
    console.log(items[i]);
}

new_one = [];
new_two = [];
new_three = [];
for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    new_one.push(items[i].name);
    new_two.push(items[i].age);
    new_three.push(items[i].last_name);
}
console.log(new_one);
console.log(new_two);
console.log(new_three);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to first sort the *first array* and then **based on the index of "one", "two", etc you want to sort the 2nd and 3rd array**.

Other answers are assuming that both 2nd and 3rd array are already sorted w.r.t. first array. Following answer assumes that 2nd and 3rd array could be in their own order and you want them to be sorted by new indexes of "one", "two", etc .

**First map *"one", "two", etc* to a number**

```
var map = { "one" : 1, "two": 2, "three" : 3, "four" : 4, "five" : 5 };
```

Sort the first array and get the latest indexes

```
array_one.sort( ( a, b ) => a.localeCompare(b) );
```

Get the new indexes to create 2nd array

```
array_two = array_one.map( s => map[s.split("_")[1]] );
```

And use the same logic to get 3rd array

```
array_three.sort( function(a,b){
   var numA = map[a.split( "_" )[1]];
   var numB = map[b.split( "_" )[1]];
   return array_two.indexOf(numA) -  array_two.indexOf(numB);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
let array_one = ["bravo_one", "charlie_two", "alpha_three", "echo_four", "delta_five"];
let array_two = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let array_three = ["golf_one", "zulu_two", "tango_three", "november_four", "kilo_five"];


var map = {
  "one": 1,
  "two": 2,
  "three": 3,
  "four": 4,
  "five": 5
};


array_one.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));


array_two = array_one.map(s => map[s.split("_")[1]]);
array_three.sort( function(a,b){
   var numA = map[a.split( "_" )[1]];
   var numB = map[b.split( "_" )[1]];
   return array_two.indexOf(numA) -  array_two.indexOf(numB);
});

console.log(array_one, array_two,array_three);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one matrix with yours lists, sort one and change the others by reference:

```js
// Change position between two items
Array.prototype.swap = function(a,b,u) {
    this.moved = this.moved || [];
    if(u && this.moved.indexOf(a) != -1 && this.moved.indexOf(b) != -1) return false;
    this.tmp = this[a];
    this[a] = this[b];
    this[b] = this.tmp;
    this.moved.push(a);
    this.moved.push(b);
};

// Change order of all arrays by reference
function orderby(matriz,line){
    line = line || 0;
    var moded = [];
    var oders = matriz[line].slice(0,matriz[line].lenght);
    matriz[line].sort();
    for(var j = 0; j < oders.length; j++){
        k = matriz[line].indexOf(oders[j])
        for(var n = 0; n < matriz.length; n++){
            n != line && matriz[n].swap(j,k,1);
        }
    }
}

// Array X Array = Matriz
var matriz = [
    ["alpha_one", "bravo_two", "charlie_three", "delta_four", "echo_five"], //line 0
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], //line 1
    ["tango_one", "zulu_two", "golf_three", "november_four", "kilo_five"] //line 2
]

var line = 2; //We will order all lines by reference line 2

orderby(matriz,line);

console.log(matriz[0]);
console.log(matriz[1]);
console.log(matriz[2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```